# How to get data from another page html using the same script.js?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm really struggling with this, I'm using fetch to get data from rest API countries, and displaying some countries in index.html.  My case is that when I click on a country, I want to move to detail.html and display more data from the country I clicked on.  I don't know how to deal with this.  I tried to use the same script.js in detail.html and hoped to get the e.target from the `addEventListener`, but the code collided as a result.  It would be much easier if I created a modal in index.html, but instead of doing that I want to move to a different page and get my skills increased a bit. Should I use a backend in this case?

If you'd like to see the preview site or the codes here are the links [site](https://sam-dev-pixel.github.io/rest-countries-api-with-color-theme-switcher-master/), [code](https://github.com/SAM-dev-pixel/rest-countries-api-with-color-theme-switcher-master)

Comment: What will the source be for the detail data? Another api fetch request?

Comment: I think you can use myStorage = window.localStorage;

Comment: Before moving to details.html, you can set which is selected, and you can get that on details.html, and call api with that, and show details.

Comment: @charlietfl yes, click the country and fetch again by its name or dataset, then display it in detail.html

Comment: So a simple approach you can try is pass an identifier in the url as a search parameter. Then when you load the detail.html page read that from the url and use it to make a new fetch request. Something like `/detail.html?countryId=1357`

Comment: @WangYinXing so I need to store all the countries or only country that I clicked on?

Comment: You can set the selected country only, and get that on details page, and call api for getting the details by selected country

Comment: var obj = {
    fruit: "banana",
    fruit2: "apple",
    fruit3: "orange"
};
//Store
localStorage.setItem("obj", JSON.stringify(obj));
//Then retrieve
var localObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(obj));
alert(localObj.fruit);

Comment: Like above code, you can set selected country, and get that on details.html page, and call api to get details for selected country.

Comment: @WangYinXing but how to handle the crash code in detail.html?

Comment: What do you mean by crash code?

Comment: @WangYinXing I am using one script.js in two html pages.  But the code that should run in index.html is also executed in detail.html

Comment: So you want to use one jscript file for both two pages?

Comment: Yes that I was thought, or you have a better solution?

Comment: I think you can use 2 script file

Comment: Or you can check url by javascript

Comment: How to check url in js?

Comment: window.location.href

Comment: Using one script file in multiple pages is very common. As for reading the url that is an easy search to learn how

Comment: Well I amm going to try all of these solutions

Comment: I think you can define functions that use for multiple pages on one script file

Answer (score 0):

You can store the selected Country name using local storage. For example

```
localStorage.setItem("Country", "Afghanistan");
```

and get the country name in your detail.html page like this.

```
var country=localStorage.getItem("Country");
```

Then simply send the request to API for get the data about that particular country(Afghanistan) and display it in your detail.html page.

Answer (score -1):

You can store the selected country on window object, or any global variable. Then on details page, use that country details to display.

Comment: Each page has it's own window and knows nothing about the other page's window

Comment: this is single page app, it can share the window object for all pages

Comment: OP made no mention of an SPA, although that would make it helpful

Comment: It's spa from what I can see in the source code

Comment: @charlietfl but how to handle crash code in detail.html?